# Environment-specific web.xml in grails?

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, groovy

What's the best way to build environment-specific `web.xml` entries in grails?

I need to make certain modifications for production only, as they break running locally.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create `scripts/_Events.groovy` with an event handler for the 'WebXmlEnd' event which is fired once Grails and the plugins have finished making their changes. Update the XML with plain search/replace or via DOM methods by parsing the XML and write out the updated file:

```
import grails.util.Environment

eventWebXmlEnd = { String filename ->

   if (Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION) {
      return
   }

   String content = webXmlFile.text

   // update the XML
   content = ...

   webXmlFile.withWriter { file -> file << content }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the solution that's i'm using, from the guy over at death-head.ch

first install the templates

```
grails install-templates
```

then customize the `web.xml` you'll find in `src/templates/war/web.xml`.  I chose to make a `web_dev.xml` and a `web_prod.xml` and delete the `web.xml`.    I wanted `web_prod.xml` to contain a security-constraint block. anyway...

Place the following in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
// #########################################################
// ## Can't use environment switching block because BuildConfig doesn't support it.
// ##    @url http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4260
// ## So use this workaround:
// ##   @url http://death-head.ch/blog/2010/09/finally-solved-the-base-authentication-in-grails/
// #########################################################

switch ("${System.getProperty('grails.env')}") {
  case "development":
    if (new File("/${basedir}/src/templates/war/web_dev.xml").exists()) {
        grails.config.base.webXml = "file:${basedir}/src/templates/war/web_dev.xml"
    }
    break;
  default:
    if (new File("/${basedir}/src/templates/war/web_prod.xml").exists()) {
        grails.config.base.webXml = "file:${basedir}/src/templates/war/web_prod.xml"
    }
    break;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This works well.  Instead of using `"${System.getProperty('grails.env')}"` I read from `grails.util.Environment.getCurrent().getName()` in Grails 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but it *should* be possible to specify the `grails.config.base.webXml` parameter in `BuildConfig.groovy` dependant on the current environment.

There's a [list of available BuildConfig settings here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.3%20Hooking%20into%20Events)

---

EDIT

Actually, [due to this issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4260), this isn't a way forward :-(  Maybe passing the property like:

```
grails -Dgrails.config.base.webXml=/path/to/web.xml
```

Is all that's possible?