# Maven Grails web.xml

Tags: maven, grails, web.xml

Might be a stupid question, but in my current maven project i do not have a web.xml in my /web-app/WEB-INF folder.

There is no web-xml in my project and never has been, im trying to add it but my application is non-responsive to anything written in the web.xml. What am i missing?, iv tried specifying the path to it through the config.groovy like:

```
grails.project.web.xml="web-app/WEB-INF/web.xml"
```

Am i missing something? Do i need to specify the web.xml in some other config file in order to make my project utilize it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
grails install-templates
```

to copy templates that Grails uses for all code generation activities (including "web.xml").

"web.xml" file will be created in "src/templates/war" directory.

Comment: Fine, i can generate the templates, no problem. But my application is still not responding to any changes made to the web.xml file, am i suppose to move any of this files or are they in their correct path when generated?

Comment: Keep the files where they were generated. Changes made in "src/templates/war/web.xml" should affect your application.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891646/107847. It doesn't install separate web.xml but does allow you add what ever content you need or edit any of the generated content.