# URLRewriteFilter in Development Environment?

Tags: grails, development-environment, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using UrlRewriteFilter to forward all requests to my domain to the "www" version for SEO.
I have a basic rule:

```
<rule>
<name>Domain Name Check</name>
<condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.mydomain.com</condition>
<from>/.*</from>
<to type="permanent-redirect">http://www.mydomain.com</to>
</rule>
```

This works great for production, but when I am running in development mode it changes my domain as well, from `localhost:8080/mysite` to `www.mydomain.com`.

How can I fix this up for development mode? I am using Grails and Tomcat, so everything is bundled in a .war that gets deployed to the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the [UrlRewritePlugin](http://grails.org/plugin/urlrewrite)?

Comment: No, I just pulled in the files manually. That looked pretty old and had no reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this in `BuildConfig.groovy` to exclude the dependency? (provided you have not added the jar in `lib`)

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        if (Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION)
            excludes "urlrewritefilter"
    }
}
```

If that does not work then in my opinion the safest bet will be to fork/clone the [plugin](https://github.com/lesiki/grails-url-rewrite-plugin) (which uses the latest version of `urlrewritefilter:4.0.3`) and modify `UrlRewriteGrailsPlugin.groovy` by adding the below elements:

```
def environments = ['prod'] //or 'production'
def scopes = [excludes:'run'] //If you normally use run-app in development
```

and use the plugin instead of adding the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to exclude the lib. Instead, you can define [different web.xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888980/environment-specific-web-xml-in-grails) for development and for production. And you just include the UrlRewriteFilter in the production.