# Grails war command: what happens behind the scene

Tags: java, grails, war

I know that in Grails framework, you can build a war file using

**grails war**(builds a production war)

or you can build a environment-specific war file using

**grails test war**

Now, what I am having trouble understanding is, if I build a war file using **grails war** but deploy it to **test environment** (where -Dgrails.env=test), the war file built using **grails war** command runs happily by picking up **test ** environment settings(like pulling data from test urls instead of prod urls).

My question is: what is the point of building a war file using a environment-specific command (ie. why use **grails test war** when the war file built using **grails war** works everywhere?).

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for using an environment is because you may code in your application that hooks into the build process and alters the resulting WAR based on the environment. Such as re configuring some filters in `web.xml` for instance. It's an extension point. You can use it if you need.

Comment: Right. I understand that. But, in grails world, one puts then in the Environment specific blocks in Config.groovy or Datasources.groovy

Comment: See edits to answer regarding web.xml reconfiguration.

Comment: thanks. Is there any place where I can get more info on this?

Comment: Here is an example of what I mentioned. Keep in mind this is just ONE possibility for customization of your WAR based on environment. There are plenty of others. Such as swapping out assets, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888980/environment-specific-web-xml-in-grails

Answer (score 2):

Grails holds three automatic environments: dev, test, prod.  there are some
defaults for the various "scripts", e.g. run-app runs dev, test-app runs test,
war build a war for prod.  these are there for convenience and make the most
sense from the daily usage patterns for developers.  e.g. in testing the
default is an in-mem db.

You can also add more environments, as you see fit.  E.g. having an `staging`
or `integration` environment is common, so by providing such an env (maybe
only some config or db changes) you can easily build a war file for the server
you use for your QA team.

Another use case is to just build a dev war, as there might be something odd
with the war on the production server and you just need to run the war against
that odd tomcat 6.x real-life environment, but with the dev setting against
your db.

That said, there still is the config you can add via config files, but the
environments give a rather sane setup for "all involved", as they are usually
within version control.

And as a final step you still have access to the environment in your own
`scripts/_Events.groovy` hooks, where you might e.g. drop or add something,
but that only makes sense for that exact environment (e.g. drop some jars, as
they are on the server already).

At the end, this features gives you some freedom to do what you want. Be glad, if you never have to use it.  But once you need, you'll be glad it's there.